# Why does the scrollbar disappear into the bottom of my divs in an app with an off-view side div?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow, sidebar

I'm trying to build a responsive app with off-view side content, modeled after this tutorial: 
http://scotch.io/tutorials/off-canvas-menus-with-css3-transitions-and-transforms

The tutorial doesn't allow for separate scrolling of the main content and the side content, and I'm having trouble building this function satisfactorily.

Through different nesting and hiding, I've gotten the two different divs to scroll separately, but I'm unable to scroll to the bottom of either div when the browser window is less than about 600 pixels high. The scrollbar disappears into the bottom of the window. See pic below.

Why is this happening? Thank you.

[image: Unable to scroll to bottom of div. Scrollbar disappears into bottom of window.]

**DEMO: http://jsbin.com/zotow/1/ (reduce browser window height below 600px to see error)**

HTML:

```
<body>

  <div id="page">

    <div id="view">

      <div id="content">

        <div id="side">
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>

        <div id="side-btn">?</div>

        <div id="main">
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>

      </div>

    </div

  </div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
@charset 'UTF-8';

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#page {
  min-width: 320px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 568px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

#view {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 426px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 568px;
  max-height: 768px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#content {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 426px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 568px;
  max-height: 768px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s linear all;
  -moz-transition: 0.25s linear all;
  -o-transition: 0.25s linear all;
  transition: 0.25s linear all;
}

#content.show-side {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(280px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(280px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(280px);
  -o-transform: translateX(280px);
  transform: translateX(280px);
}

#side {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 280px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -280px;
  padding: 14px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.333;
  overflow: auto;
}

#side-btn {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: #0010cc;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#side-btn:hover {
  background-color: #999dcc;
}

#main {
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 426px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 568px;
  max-height: 768px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

JS:

```
var app = {};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  app.content = document.getElementById('content');
  app.sideBtn = document.getElementById('side-btn');

  app.sideBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(!app.content.className) {
      app.content.className = 'show-side';
    } else {
      app.content.className = '';
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `min-height: 568px;` from your divs and the scrolling should work. `Min-height` is forcing the divs to extend past the edge of the browser window.